# how to differentiate between buyer and seller in smart contract?

Tags: solidity

I'm creating a new token in BSC using Solidity, and I want to identified when someone is buying, so I can make the contract do something specific

How can I identified when someone is BUYING? thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share what you've tried so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.